# Pandas: Fill first spare rows with new updated data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let say I have a `base_df` I wish to update with new data from `new_df`.

`base_df` could be a dataframe as the following. Where at some point `FC` and `FF` faults were removed, and that indexes were marked as Spare

```
base_df = pd.DataFrame({'Fault': ['FA','FB','Spare1','FD','FE','Spare2'], 
                   'Description' : ['Des for FA','Des for FB','Des for FC','Des for FD',\
                                    'Des for FE','Des for FF']})
base_df
    Fault   Description
0   FA      Des for FA
1   FB      Des for FB
2   Spare   Des for FC
3   FD      Des for FD
4   FE      Des for FE
5   Spare   Des for FF
```

In the `new_df` a fault could be missing (e.g. `FB`) and it could contain new rows (e.g.`FG`,`FH`,`FI` and `FJ`). However `new_df` will never contain nor NaN or Spare rows.

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'Fault': ['FA','FD','FE','FG','FH','FI'], 
                   'Description' : ['Des for FA','Des for FD','Des for FE',\
                                    'Des for FG','Des for FH','Des for FI']})
new_df
    Fault   Description
0   FA      Des for FA
1   FD      Des for FD
2   FE      Des for FE
3   FG      Des for FG
4   FH      Des for FH
5   FI      Des for FI
6   FJ      Des for FJ
```

To update `base_df` with `new_df` the following rules should be followed:

1. If in `new_df` is missing a fault that appears in `base_df`, it is marked as Spare in `updated_df`.
2. If in `new_df` are new faults, first it should fill Spare rows. If there are not spare rows, they can be added to the end.

With the previous example, the `updated_df` should finish as per below.

```
updated_df = pd.DataFrame({'Fault': ['FA','FG','FH','FD','FE','FI','FJ'], 
                   'Description' : ['Des for FA','Des for FG','Des for FH','Des for FD',\
                                    'Des for FE','Des for FI','Des for FJ']})
updated_df
    Fault   Description
0   FA      Des for FA
1   FG      Des for FG
2   FH      Des for FH
3   FD      Des for FD
4   FE      Des for FE
5   FI      Des for FI
6   FJ      Des for FJ
```

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

- Description for Spare rows can be removed, set as Nan or the easyest value to work with
- In a second step I would like also to mark the new added rows in green and the deleted rows saved in a df apart

Comment: I can't understand your rules. If you reordered the rows, `updated_df` is exactly the same as `new_df`

Comment: I agree with @CodeDifferent.  I don't understand what is going on.

Comment: @CodeDifferent,@pirRSquared. The ideas was to check in `new_df` wich faults were missing, mark them as spare in a copy of `base_df`. Then check for new faults, and add them filling first spare rows.
The rows that have not been modified should keep the index from base_df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

```
fault1=list(base_df.Fault)
fault2=list(new_df.Fault)
i=0
updated_df=base_df
for k in fault1:
    i=i+1
    if k not in fault2:
        updated_df.loc[i-1,'Fault']="Spare"
        updated_df.loc[i-1,'Description']="Spare"



for k in fault2:
    if k not in list(updated_df.Fault):
        try:
            i=list(updated_df.Fault).index('Spare')
            updated_df.loc[i,'Fault']=k
            updated_df.loc[i,'Description']=new_df[new_df.Fault==k].Description.values[0]
        except:
            updated_df.loc[len(updated_df.index)]=[k,new_df[new_df.Fault==k].Description.values[0]]
            
            
updated_df
```

[image]

Comment: what do you think of this solution? do you need any clarifications?